# NSFileNoSuchFileError when accessing NSLibraryDirectory of Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator

After a fresh setup of our CI environment various tests of one of your iOS Apps failed due to *NSFileNoSuchFileError* when accessing *NSLibraryDirectory* (~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Library) in the Simulator.

Any idea how that can happen?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you need to start the iOS Simulator at least once, in order for it to create the directory mentioned above.